# Using IN with Multiple Values in Oracle (Column_A,Column_B) IN (M,M)

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to filter out records based on two values.

The table I'm working with have student accounts. The two columns I'm looking at should satisfy the below condition.

- When Column_A contains accounts (1310001,1320002,4520004,6170004) then Column_B cannot contain accounts (1310001,1320002,4520004,6170004) and accounts starting with (12,119,03,02).
- When Column_B contains accounts (1310001,1320002,4520004,6170004) then Column_A cannot contain accounts (1310001,1320002,4520004,6170004) and accounts starting with (12,119,03,02).

Please let me know how this can be written in SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would express your logic as:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE
    (
        Column_A IN (1310001,1320002,4520004,6170004) AND
        Column_B NOT IN (1310001,1320002,4520004,6170004) AND
        NOT REGEXP_LIKE(Column_B, '^(12|119|03|02)')
    ) AND
    (
        Column_B IN (1310001,1320002,4520004,6170004) AND
        Column_A NOT IN (1310001,1320002,4520004,6170004) AND
        NOT REGEXP_LIKE(Column_A, '^(12|119|03|02)')
    );
```

Comment: @Samrox . . . As I read the question, you want `AND` between the conditions, not `OR`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff `AND` I originally had that as well, until the OP asked me to change it.